# How to get value from supabase without .execute()? - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, frontend, backend, supabase

So, Supabase announced that they're updated supabase-flutter package into v.1.0 and I want to give it a try.

This is how they're fetching data from database in previous version:

```
final res = await supabase.from('my_table').select().execute(); // <= They're using execute
final error = res.error;
if(error != null) {
  // handle error
}
final data = res.data;
```

But in this new version, they're deprecating `.execute()`.
As the [blog](https://supabase.com/blog/supabase-flutter-sdk-1-developer-preview#no-more-execute-to-get-the-data) said,

> No more .execute() to get the data
> We want this SDK to be as close as possible to the JavaScript SDK to provide consistent developer experience no matter what programming language you are using. Prior to the 1.0 update, whenever you called the postgrest endpoints, you had to call .execute() at the end of each query.

> .execute() is now deprecated. You no longer needed it to query data from your Supabase database.

This is the new syntax:

```
try {
 final data = supabase.from('my_table').select();
 // 'data' data type is PostgrestFilterBuilder
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```

How can I get value from variable 'data'? Also I want to get a single value from the data.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are missing a `await` before the `supabase.from` in your code.